# Mecerl laptop gives a an efi screen

Tags: windows, boot, efi

when I turn on my latop, a screen apear, with the following message
Efi shell version 2.40 (5.11)
map: cannot find required map name

please help

Comment: Please add a photo of the screen to your post. Do you hear any beeps when the computer starts (if yes, count them and give the model of the laptop)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.